# Stuck in comparing "++X" with another string in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, strcmp, string.h

I am trying to take a string as input and if it's equal to X++ or ++X, I would like to count it. for this purpose, I have written value code. Though it's working correctly for X++, for X-- it's not working. How can I solve the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
    int n,count=0;
    char c[5];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%s",c);
        if(strcmp(c,"X++")==1 || strcmp(c,"++X")==1) count++;
        else count--;
    }
    printf("%d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be working correctly for either of them. What makes you think it is?

Comment: Read closely the documentation of `strcmp`, especially what values it returns. Is it stated explicitely that `strcmp` can return `1`?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to change `strcmp(c,"X++")==1` to `strcmp(c,"X++")==0`, and `strcmp(c,"++X")==1` to `strcmp(c,"++X")==0`. `strcmp()` will return `0` if its arguments are equal, not `1`. You can read more about `strcmp()` [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html).

Comment: Oops. i just thought it as binary meaning. Thanks. but when i run the code why it was worked for X++?

Comment: @MdNasirAhmed As Barmar said in the comment, it'll not work for either of those. Can you give an example of what you mean by "why it worked for X++"? As a side note, you can always check the return value of `strcmp()` to understand what your program actually does.

Comment: @LonelyProgrammer Sorry, I don't know, why my ide was showing count=1 when i entered X++. But now I checked on a online compiler and also checked the return value of the condition and i found you both (you and @Barma) was correct. Thanks to you all.

Comment: @EricPostpischil what do you mean by "only one of its arguments is equal"?

Comment: @EricPostpischil My appologies, English is not my native language. I'll edit it now.

Comment: @JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer: No worries, it is just a funny thing, not an error.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I edited it. I hope it makes more sense now. Thanks for pointing it out.